# BeautifulSoup 4 in Python 3: how get table rows in a disappearing table?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I spent 5 hours trying to parse a table with exchange rates with BeautifulSoup 4 and Python 3, following guides and the bs4 manual, but part of the table magically disappears.

Here's the page: 
[The page with exhange rates I want to parse.](http://ru.kkb.kz/cards/page/Rates)

When I inspect element in browser, I see a simple table:

```
<table width="100%" align="center" class="tbl_text"><tbody id="shapka"><tr align="center"><td>Время начала действия курса </td><td colspan="2" align="center">Доллары США, USD</td><td colspan="2" align="center">Евро, EUR</td><td colspan="2" align="center">Рубли, RUB*</td></tr></tbody><tbody id="shapka_sub"><tr align="center"><td>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Покупка</b></td><td><b>Продажа</b></td><td><b>Покупка</b></td><td><b>Продажа</b></td><td><b>Покупка</b></td><td><b>Продажа</b></td></tr></tbody><tbody style="font-weight: bold;"><tr><td>06.11 c 17:36</td><td>308.56</td><td>313.81</td><td>333.87</td><td>342.81</td><td>4.752</td><td>5.107</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>06.11 c 17:16</td><td>308.56</td><td>313.81</td><td>334.24</td><td>343.15</td><td>4.752</td><td>5.107</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>06.11 c 16:46</td><td>308.56</td><td>313.81</td><td>333.93</td><td>342.78</td><td>4.752</td><td>5.107</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>06.11 c 16:26</td><td>308.56</td><td>313.81</td><td>333.93</td><td>342.78</td><td>4.743</td><td>5.096</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>06.11 c 15:56</td><td>307.06</td><td>312.3</td><td>332.25</td><td>341.13</td><td>4.728</td><td>5.083</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = input('URL: ')
url = 'http://ru.kkb.kz/cards/page/Rates'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# Attempt 1: it only gets part of table
table = s.find ('table')
print ("Attempt 1:")
print (table)

#Attempt 2: and it fails to get ALL the td tags...
tds = s('td')
print ("Attempt 2:")
print (tds)

#Attempt 3: worked once in shell but not run-time
tbody = s.find('tbody', style="font-weight: bold;")
print ("Attempt 3:")
print (tbody)

print ("Why I can't get the values in td?")
```

I always end up with part of the table with headers, but not with the values.
How can I get the second part of the table with figures?

Comment: What is the value of `html`? Are you sure?

Comment: To Peter Wood: values in html are currency exchange rates (figures). I can easily get other values on the page with bs4, so this is not related to misuse of bs4. I think @imjosh is right and I need to use POST to get or refresh the data part of the table. However, today the table features only one single row of data (weekend) and code in Attempt #3 works! On Friday the table had 4 rows and the code did not work. And when I tried to save a local copy of the page it never saved the table data, only headers. So, on Monday I want to check if the code will still work and report back.

Comment: What I mean is, are you sure it's getting back the data you think it's getting. Print out the value of `html`. Also, once you've got valid data, use that for testing instead of polling the website all the time. They might block you. Also, it'll make your tests more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a POST request with the following data and then parse the response to that:

`day=5&month=11&year=2015&view=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C`

i.e.:

> day   5
>
> month 11
>
> year  2015
>
> view   Показать

To figure this out I watched the network tab in Chrome developers tools.  Even if a page uses javascript to load data into the page (which this one doesn't, I don't think - it's just a form) you can often figure out what URL the script is getting the data from.

Comment: For the advice on digging deeper within the page.

Comment: Good work, the Russian intimidated me :).  Deleting my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's harder when the language is foreign. This is the english version of the page (though the table is simple here, it has no POST part with data unavailable for bs4): http://en.kkb.kz/page/ExchangeRates